# Sort list of Strings and Integers inplace Scala

Tags: scala, list, sorting

Is there any way in scala to sort a sort of list of integers and strings without changing there relative position ? Like if I have input

```
List("xyz",6,4,"ghi",3,5,1,"abc")
```

The output should be

```
List("abc",1,3,"ghi",4,5,6,"xyz")
```

the rhe relative position of integers and strings does not change. I did this by storing the positions of digits and numbers seperately and then sorting the strings and integers in different list and putting them back together in their respective position. Is there any technique in Scala to do it faster ?

Comment: How would you define the sorting relation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the intergers should be sorted relative to each other and place at the position in which only interger were kept. Same for strings

Comment: The easiest way would be as you did, to separate them while storing the indices and then flipping elements as you sort. Cant think of a nicer way to do it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I was hoping if there was some other way to do it, like list-comprehension in Python ?

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, you can go wild. In any statically typed language this won't be as easy...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov guess I will have to stick with brute force way then...

Comment: to hold the integers and strings in one list and them wanting to sort them independently seems conceptually flawed.

Comment: The default `List` that you get is `scala.collection.immutable.List`, which, as the fully qualified name implies, is *immutable*, so in-place sort is *by definition* impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes a working code. Probably not optimal, but it solves the problem:

```
object Test {

   def removeElementFromList[T](xs:List[T], t:T):List[T] = xs match {
      case h::tail if h == t => tail
      case h::tail if h != t => h :: removeElementFromList(tail, t)
      case Nil => Nil
   }

  def updateElement[T](xs:List[T], oldValue:T, newValue:T):List[T] = xs match{
    case h::tail if h == oldValue => newValue :: tail
    case h::tail if h != oldValue => h :: updateElement(tail, oldValue, newValue)
    case Nil => Nil
  }

  //ascending
  def sortRetainingPosition[T](xs:List[(T, Int)])(implicit cmp:Ordering[T]):List[(T, Int)] = {
    xs match{
      case h :: tail =>{
        val minimalElement = xs.minBy(_._1)
        if(h == minimalElement) h :: sortRetainingPosition(tail) else{
          (minimalElement._1, h._2) :: sortRetainingPosition(updateElement(tail, minimalElement, (h._1, minimalElement._2)))
        }
      }
      case Nil => Nil
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val input = List("xyz",6,4,"ghi",3,5,1,"abc")
    val positioned = input.zipWithIndex
    val strings = positioned.filter(_._1.isInstanceOf[String]).asInstanceOf[List[(String, Int)]]
    val ints = positioned.filterNot(_._1.isInstanceOf[String]).asInstanceOf[List[(Int, Int)]]
    val partiallySorted = sortRetainingPosition(strings) ++ sortRetainingPosition(ints)
    val result = partiallySorted.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
    println(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This really helped a lot.